# How to implement dynamic @ConfigurationProperties Prefix

Tags: spring-boot

I have a requirement to pass dynamic environment name as a prefix of configuration property. I will pass environment as VM argument from command line and all properties should be loaded for that environment.

**My Configuration**:

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@PropertySource("environmentDetails.yml")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="${environment}")
public class ConfigurationBean {

    private String brokerUrl;
    private String queueName;
    private String receiverUserName;
    private String receiverPassword;

    public String getBrokerUrl() {
        return brokerUrl;
    }
    public void setBrokerUrl(String brokerUrl) {
        this.brokerUrl = brokerUrl;
    }
    public String getQueueName() {
        return queueName;
    }
    public void setQueueName(String queueName) {
        this.queueName = queueName;
    }
    public String getReceiverUserName() {
        return receiverUserName;
    }
    public void setReceiverUserName(String receiverUserName) {
        this.receiverUserName = receiverUserName;
    }
    public String getReceiverPassword() {
        return receiverPassword;
    }
    public void setReceiverPassword(String receiverPassword) {
        this.receiverPassword = receiverPassword;
    }
}
```

**environmentDetails.yml**

```
spring:
  profiles.active: default
---
spring:
  profiles: default

environment:
  brokerUrl: http://ip:port
  queueName: testQueue
  receiverUserName: testuser
  receiverPassword: password
```

Comment: What is the question? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks Brian. When I am using ${environment} as the argument of @ConfigurationProperties, it is not working. Is there any trick to use dynamic argument which I can pass via program/VM argument in the program? I have done same thing in Spring application and it is working fine, but in case of Spring boot, it is not working.

Comment: @Saurabh, Did you find any solution, how to set 'ConfigurationProperties prefix' with VMArg?

Comment: I think you should use some `Map<String, BrokerProperties>` where key would be your dynamic environment variable. This map could collect properties with `broker.*` prefix (such as `broker.a.broker-url`, `broker.b.broker-url`)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the issue: You can't use .yml with @PropertySource: [boot-features-external-config-yaml-shortcomings](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-yaml-shortcomings)

> YAML files can’t be loaded via the @PropertySource annotation. So in the case that you need to load values that way, you need to use a properties file.

You'll have to convert to .properties to do this.

Comment: Thanks Brian for the help. I commented @PropertySource("environmentDetails.yml") and it is working fine if I am using hard coded value for prefix e.g. @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="envName"). But when I am using placeholder value for prefix e.g. @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="${envName}"). It is giving me an error. Is there any way can I use prefix with dynamic values. As per the requirement, I will have many files coming from a source with environment name in it, and I need to pick properties as per environment coming from the file name. So environment name will be dynamic.

Comment: Is this still true today?

Comment: Hi @Saurabh: I am facing similar issue, Did you get solution for this?